# Create List View Dynamically in Android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I am developing an Android app. In that I want to add List view at run time on Text click.
Here is the image of one demo.

[image]

By default there are 3 options in "List". When user clicks on Add new List option then new List should be added into header with Work, Play and buddies option. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Done it...This is the link...Visit http://code4reference.com/2012/09/android-activity-layout/